# MariaDB Logic Change with very large IN (...) set

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a particular MariaDB Query that utilizes some joins and some IN ('...') conditions.
Generally it returns results in < 2sec on large data sets (~50M records), however when a very large number of options are presented in the IN condition, (Eg. 1000+ IN options) the query takes 5+ hours and the logic completely changes when running an ANALYZE on the queries.

Looking to understand why this is the case and suggestions on how I might be able to resolve the bottleneck. Presently thinking the simplest option may be to drop the IN condition completely and filter the results in PHP instead of SQL, as if the IN condition is dropped results are returned in <1s on same tables.

ANALYZE results from query where small IN set used.

```
+------+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+-------+---------+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys          | key      | key_len | ref                | rows  | r_rows  | filtered | r_filtered | Extra                                                               |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+-------+---------+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | range | calldate,call_id       | calldate | 7       | NULL               | 13400 | 7162.00 |   100.00 |      33.01 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | ref   | PRIMARY,called,call_id | call_id  | 4       | crimson.t1.call_id |     1 |    3.21 |   100.00 |      35.24 | Using where                                                         |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | d1    | ref   | digits,leg_id          | leg_id   | 4       | crimson.t2.xid     |     1 |    1.94 |   100.00 |       0.58 | Using index condition; Using where                                  |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | g1    | ref   | call_id                | call_id  | 4       | crimson.t1.call_id |     1 |    3.00 |   100.00 |       0.00 | Using where                                                         |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+-------+---------+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (1.154 sec)
```

ANALYZE results from the same query and conditions where 1200 IN set has been used.

```
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+---------+----------+------------+---------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table       | type   | possible_keys          | key     | key_len | ref                | rows | r_rows  | filtered | r_filtered | Extra                           |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+---------+----------+------------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2> | ALL    | distinct_key           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL               | 1222 | 1222.00 |   100.00 |     100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | d1          | ref    | digits,leg_id          | digits  | 29      | tvc_0._col_1       |    5 | 6192.72 |   100.00 |     100.00 | Using index condition           |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | t2          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,called,call_id | PRIMARY | 8       | crimson.d1.leg_id  |    1 |    1.00 |   100.00 |      36.73 | Using where                     |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | g1          | ref    | call_id                | call_id | 4       | crimson.t2.call_id |    1 |    3.32 |   100.00 |       0.05 | Using where                     |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | t1          | ref    | calldate,call_id       | call_id | 4       | crimson.t2.call_id |    1 |    5.19 |   100.00 |       0.03 | Using where                     |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | <derived3>  | ALL    | NULL                   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL               | 1222 | 1222.00 |   100.00 |     100.00 |                                 |
|    3 | DERIVED      | NULL        | NULL   | NULL                   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL               | NULL |    NULL |     NULL |       NULL | No tables used                  |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+---------+----------+------------+---------------------------------+
7 rows in set (5 hours 16 min 16.738 sec)
```

ANALYZE without any IN condition at all.

```
+------+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+-------+---------+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys          | key      | key_len | ref                | rows  | r_rows  | filtered | r_filtered | Extra                                                               |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+-------+---------+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | range | calldate,call_id       | calldate | 7       | NULL               | 13400 | 7162.00 |   100.00 |      33.01 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | ref   | PRIMARY,called,call_id | call_id  | 4       | crimson.t1.call_id |     1 |    3.21 |   100.00 |      35.24 | Using where                                                         |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | g1    | ref   | call_id                | call_id  | 4       | crimson.t1.call_id |     1 |    3.57 |   100.00 |       0.06 | Using where                                                         |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | d1    | ref   | leg_id                 | leg_id   | 4       | crimson.t2.xid     |     1 |    1.33 |   100.00 |     100.00 | Using index condition                                               |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+-------+---------+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.093 sec)
```

Example Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `digit_dial_map_x` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `leg_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sequence` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `digits` varchar(26) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M',  
  INDEX `leg_id` (`leg_id`),
  INDEX `digits` (`digits`),
  INDEX `category` (`category`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `call_legs_x` (
  `xid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `call_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `calldate` date NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration_hr` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration_min` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration_sec` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `calling` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `called` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ans` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ans_time` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `digits_dialed` varchar(26) DEFAULT NULL,
  `digits_actual` varchar(26) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ani` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dnis` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extn` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_conf` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `third_party` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sysid` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `call_log_id` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assoc_log_id` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `raw_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `leg` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `call_start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `call_end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `call_start_utc` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `call_end_utc` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  INDEX `calldate` (`calldate`, `start_time`),
  INDEX `called` (`called`),
  INDEX `call_id` (`call_id`),
  INDEX `digits_dialed` (`digits_dialed`),
  INDEX `raw_id` (`raw_id`),
  INDEX `call_start` (`call_start`),
  INDEX `call_end` (`call_end`),
  INDEX `call_start_utc` (`call_start`),
  INDEX `call_end_utc` (`call_end`),
  INDEX `calling` (`calling`),
  INDEX `ans_time` (`ans_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Example Query (omitted the 1200 IN options):

```
SELECT t1.call_id, t2.ans_time, t2.ans, ((t2.duration_hr * 3600) + (t2.duration_min *60) + t2.duration_sec) as duration, t2.digits_dialed, t2.digits_actual, t2.dnis, t2.trans_conf, t1.ani, t1.calling, t2.called, d1.digits, g1.extn
  FROM call_legs_55 as t1
  JOIN call_legs_55 as t2 ON t1.call_id=t2.call_id
  JOIN digit_dial_map_55 as d1 ON t2.xid=d1.leg_id
  JOIN call_legs_55 as g1 ON t1.call_id=g1.call_id
  WHERE (t1.calldate BETWEEN '2019-11-25' AND '2019-11-25') AND NOT ((t1.calldate = '2019-11-25') AND (t1.start_time < '00:00:00')) AND NOT((t1.calldate = '2019-11-25') AND (t1.start_time > '24:00:00'))
  AND (t1.calling IN ('T6001','T6002') )
  AND d1.digits IN ('...')
  AND t2.called !='X9999'
  AND t1.calling != 'X9999'
  AND t1.calling != ''
  AND t2.ans_time != ''
  AND (g1.extn IN ('52043','52042','52132','52116') AND g1.extn != t1.calling)
  GROUP BY CONCAT(t1.call_id, g1.extn);
```

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE TABLEs` and the `SELECT`.  Also the version number of MariaDB.

Comment: @RickJames I have added the relevant tables and query (omitting the 1200 IN digits options) to the question. Thanks

Comment: You may ask about the self join, this is unfortunately something I haven't been able to get around due to the nature of the data. There is an A part and a B part in many cases in the same table and the self join is used to construct a bridge between the two where they exist.

Comment: I see 2 indexes named `digits` -- perhaps a typo?  I see no `PRIMARY KEYs`.

Comment: `GROUP BY CONCAT(t1.call_id, g1.extn)` is not quite the same as `GROUP BY t1.call_id, g1.extn`.  You probably want the latter.

Comment: `ON t1.call_id=t2.call_id` -- Is that joining 1 row to itself?  Or maybe multiple rows to each other?

Comment: @RickJames yes typo on the digits index.
The GROUP BY statement is concatenated so that we we can receive a result for a particular call ID multiple times IF the extn result is different.
Eg. Call ID 12323 will be returned per unique extension.
The join is to join multiple rows in the same table if they exist. If they don't exist, it does join the same row.

Comment: What version of MariaDB?

Comment: But...  For call_id=123 and extn=4567 will be grouped (due to the CONCAT) as equal to call_id=1234 and extn=567 !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203065/discussion-between-jemson-and-rick-james).

Answer (score 0):

digit_dial_map_x is a many:many mapping table, correct??  It's indexes are very inefficient.

Recommend:

```
PRIMARY KEY(leg_id, digits),
INDEX(digits, leg_id)
```

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

(The table did not happen to be such.)